# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "(": syntax

Tags: android, sqlite, compiler-errors, android-sqlite, logcat

I try to save data in my app database for a while but i still get the same issue. Here is what my code looks like.

In the database page:

```
public void insererTrajetTest (String et_VilleD, String et_VilleA, String 
et_LieuDepart, String et_LieuArrivee,String et_dateDepartAller, String 
et_heureDepartAller, String et_flexibilite, String et_bagage, String et_detour, 
String et_iduser, String et_trajet, String et_commentaire, String et_place, 
String et_dateArriveeAller, String et_heureArriveeAller, String et_prix, String 
et_distance, String et_duree) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME3;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_VILLE_DEPART, et_VilleD);
    values.put(COLUMN_VILLE_ARRIVEE, et_VilleA);
    values.put(COLUMN_LIEU_DEPART, et_LieuDepart);
    values.put(COLUMN_LIEU_ARRIVEE, et_LieuArrivee);
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE_DEPART, et_dateDepartAller);
    values.put(COLUMN_HEURE_DEPART, et_heureDepartAller);
    values.put(COLUMN_FLEXIBILITE, et_flexibilite);
    values.put(COLUMN_BAGAGE, et_bagage);
    values.put(COLUMN_DETOUR, et_detour);
    values.put(COLUMN_ID_CHAUFFEUR, et_iduser);
    values.put(COLUMN_TRAJET, et_trajet);
    values.put(COLUMN_COMMENTAIRE, et_commentaire);
    values.put(COLUMN_PLACES_PROPOSEES, et_place);
    values.put(COLUMN_PLACES_DISPONIBLES, et_place);
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE_ARRIVEE, et_dateArriveeAller);
    values.put(COLUMN_HEURE_ARRIVEE, et_heureArriveeAller);
    values.put(COLUMN_PRIX, et_prix);
    values.put(COLUMN_DISTANCE, et_distance);
    values.put(COLUMN_DUREE, et_duree);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME3, null, values);
    Log.d("Base de données", "Un nouveau voyage a été créé...");
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
}
```

However I always get the followings in the logcat:

```
    09-18 22:15:49.986 4108-4427/cm.opep.opep E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "(": syntax error
09-18 22:15:49.990 4108-4427/cm.opep.opep E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting VilleDépart=Abong-Mbang Trajet=Abong-Mbang --> Ambam: HeureDépart=23:45 DateDépart=2018-09-28 Flexibilité=+/- 30 minutes HeureArrivée=05:59 Bagage=Petit Commentaire=Nine LieuArrivée=Er VilleArrivée=Ambam Durée=06 h 14 min DateArrivée=2018-09-29 LieuDépart=Az IDChauffeur=5 Détour=+/- 15 minutes Prix=3100 Distance(Km)=422 PlacesDisponibles=5 PlacesProposées=5
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Voyage(VilleDépart,Trajet,HeureDépart,DateDépart,Flexibilité,HeureArrivée,Bagage,Commentaire,LieuArrivée,VilleArrivée,Durée,DateArrivée,LieuDépart,IDChauffeur,Détour,Prix,Distance(Km),PlacesDisponibles,PlacesProposées) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at cm.opep.opep.DatabaseHelper.insererTrajetTest(DatabaseHelper.java:1328)
        at cm.opep.opep.fragment.BackGroundTask.doInBackground(BackGroundTask.java:56)
        at cm.opep.opep.fragment.BackGroundTask.doInBackground(BackGroundTask.java:12)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can anyone tell me what goes wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is with the column named **Distance(Km)**, to use such a column name. You'd have to enclose it e.g.

```
Prix,`Distance(Km)`,PlacesDisponibles,
```

You could do this bay changing **`COLUMN_DISTANCE`** to be defined using

```
COLUMN_DISTANCE = "`Distance(Km)`"
```

This would result in :

```
INSERT INTO Voyage(VilleDépart,Trajet,HeureDépart,DateDépart,Flexibilité,HeureArrivée,Bagage,Commentaire,LieuArrivée,VilleArrivée,Durée,DateArrivée,LieuDépart,IDChauffeur,Détour,Prix,`Distance(Km)`,PlacesDisponibles,PlacesProposées) VALUES (
    'Abong-Mbang','Abong-Mbang --> Ambam:','23:45','2018-09-28','+/- 30 minutes','05:59','Petit','Nine','Er','Ambam','06 h 14 min','2018-09-29',
    'Az',5,'+/- 15 minutes',3100,422,5,5
    );
```

Which works as per :-

```
INSERT INTO Voyage(VilleDépart,Trajet,HeureDépart,DateDépart,Flexibilité,HeureArrivée,Bagage,Commentaire,LieuArrivée,VilleArrivée,Durée,DateArrivée,LieuDépart,IDChauffeur,Détour,Prix,`Distance(Km)`,PlacesDisponibles,PlacesProposées) VALUES (
    'Abong-Mbang','Abong-Mbang --> Ambam:','23:45','2018-09-28','+/- 30 minutes','05:59','Petit','Nine','Er','Ambam','06 h 14 min','2018-09-29',
    'Az',5,'+/- 15 minutes',3100,422,5,5
    )
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.23s
```

Note for the column to exist then it's name must have been enclosed when the table was defined.

However, I'd suggest renaming the column to **Distance_Km**.

There are alternative enclosing characters you could also use

- **"Distance(Km)"** i.e. enclosed in **"** and **"**
- **[Distance(Km)]** i.e. enclosed in **[** and **]**
- **'Distance(Km)'** i.e. enclosed in **'** and **'**

This is covered at [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)